# Python + Scrapy, only saving 1 item to db, Iteration

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm playing around with Python and the Scrapy library, the idea is to spider a url , saving the desired fields into a db (in this case news items), unfortunately it currently only saves 1 list item and not several.. It does not seem to iterate correctly.

Very thankful for any help

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import Join, MapCompose
from scraper_app.items import ListItem

class ListSpider(BaseSpider):

    name = "news_list"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.example.com/Default/Section/1"]

    news_items_xpath = '//*[@id="section-news"]/section/ul/li[1]/div'
    item_fields = { 'title': './/div/h3',
    'link': './/div/h3/a',
    'description': './/div/p/text()',
    'date': './/div/div[2]'}


    def parse(self, response):

        selector = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        # iterate over deals
        for news in selector.select(self.news_items_xpath):
            loader = XPathItemLoader(ListItem(), selector=news)

            # define processors
            loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
            loader.default_output_processor = Join()

            # iterate over fields and add xpaths to the loader
            for field, xpath in self.item_fields.iteritems():
                loader.add_xpath(field, xpath)
            yield loader.load_item()
```

HTML:

```
<div id="section-news" class="block secondary">
            <section class="inner">
                <ul class="thumbs">
                    <li>
                        <div>
                            <div class="img">
                                <a href="/Detail/2015/01/14/393107/AntiIsraelism-not-antiSemitism"><img src="http://217.218.67.233/photo/20150114/59b5efd9-3c1c-47b1-a014-4ca0fedadeb6.jpg" alt="uk jews" /><i class="icon-play"></i></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="desc">
                                <h3 class="title"><a href="/Detail/2015/01/14/393107/AntiIsraelism-not-antiSemitism">‘Anti-Israelism not anti-Semitism’</a></h3>
                                <div class="date">Wed Jan 14, 2015 7:27PM</div>
                                <p>A new survey which reveals that nearly half of Britons hold anti-Semitic views.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div>
                            <div class="img">
                                <a href="/Detail/2015/01/14/393095/Turkey-bans-arms-delivery-reports"><img src="http://217.218.67.233/photo/20150114/2de1eb77-ba2a-49c9-a232-ab4cf82ffc1d.jpg" alt="Syria-militants" /></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="desc">
                                <h3 class="title"><a href="/Detail/2015/01/14/393095/Turkey-bans-arms-delivery-reports">Turkey bans arms delivery reports</a></h3>
                                <div class="date">Wed Jan 14, 2015 7:22PM</div>
                                <p>Turkey bans media reports on alleged arms delivery to militants in Syria.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div>
                            <div class="img">
                                <a href="/Detail/2015/01/14/393099/Egypt-Israel-gas-imports-possible"><img src="http://217.218.67.233/photo/20150114/c63935fb-8221-43fc-8103-6f49f013cbfd.jpg" alt="Egypt-Israel" /></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="desc">
                                <h3 class="title"><a href="/Detail/2015/01/14/393099/Egypt-Israel-gas-imports-possible">Egypt: Israel gas imports possible</a></h3>
                                <div class="date">Wed Jan 14, 2015 7:11PM</div>
                                <p>Egypt says importing gas from Israel is a possibility.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your xpath is limited to a single list entry

```
news_items_xpath = '//*[@id="section-news"]/section/ul/li[1]/div'
```

Remove the [1]

```
news_items_xpath = '//*[@id="section-news"]/section/ul/li/div'
```